# What are some other possible sources Git Bash could be pulling from other than ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile

Tags: windows, alias, git-bash

I have customized Git Bash for windows to my liking, but I was trying to add some new aliases today and I seem to have messed up. When I load up bash now, I get multiple alias: not found messages in my terminal (i.e: bash: alias: pycharm not found), however I checked ~/.bashrc and ~/.bash_profile and these aliases are not in there, they were before but I sourced them and restarted git bash, and they're not there now.

I remember working with a few other files but I don't remember where and now I'm stuck. Is there a command I can give to see what other files it could be pulling from? Or a place where I can see that information? Tried searching for 30 minutes but couldn't find anything specific enough to figure this out.

I removed the commands from .bashrc and .bash_profile, saved the file, typed source .bashrc and source .bash_profile, and restarted bash but the alias errors still keep popping up. I must have either saved these aliases in some other file as well, or they got transposed from .bashrc or .bash_profile when I had them in there before, but either way, I can't figure out the source of the errors.

Comment: What /etc file was the culprit in your case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the `/etc` folder (for any recently modified) files.

You would get `/etc/profile.d`, `/etc/bashrc`, `/etc/bashrc.bashrc`.

Make sure the error is not related to a `git config alias` as well.
From a repository, do a `git config -l --show-origin --show-scope`.